# __cdecl results in larger executable than __stdcall?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, calling-convention

I found this:

> Because the stack is cleaned by the called function, the __stdcall
>   calling convention creates **smaller** executables than __cdecl, in which
>   the *code for stack cleanup must be generated for each function call*.

Suppose I got 2 functions:

```
void __cdecl func1(int x)
{
    //do some stuff using x
}

void __stdcall func2(int x, int y)
{
    //do some stuff using x, y
}
```

and here in the `main()`:

```
int main()
{
    func1(5);
    func2(5, 6);
}
```

IMO, it is `main()`'s responsibility to clean up the stack of the call to `func1(5)`, and `func2` will clean up the stack of the call to `func2(5,6)`, right?

**Four questions:**

1.For the call to `func1` in `main()`, it's `main`'s responsibility to clean up the stack, so will compiler insert some code (code to clean up the stack) before and after the call to `func`? Like this:

```
int main()
{
    before_call_to_cdecl_func(); //compiler generated code for stack-clean-up of cdecl-func-call
    func1(5);
    after_call_to_cdecl_func(); //compiler generated code for stack-clean-up of cdecl-func-call

    func2(5, 6);
}
```

2.For the call to `func2` in `main()`, it's `func2`'s own job to clean up the stack, so I presume, no code will be inserted in `main()` before or after the call to `func2`, right?

3.Because `func2` is `__stdcall`, so I presume, compiler will automatically insert code (to clean up the stack) like this:

```
void __stdcall func1(int x, int y)
{
    before_call_to_stdcall_func(); //compiler generated code for stack-clean-up of stdcall-func-call
    //do some stuff using x, y
    after_call_to_cdecl_func(); //compiler generated code for stack-clean-up of stdcall-func-call
}
```

I presume right?

4.Finally, back to the quoted words, why `__stdcall` results in smaller executable than `__cdecl`? And there is no such a thing as `__stdcall` in linux, right? Does it means linux elf will be always larger than exe in win?

Comment: stdcall cannot be used for variadic functions which is why you don't tend to see it on Linux. It's only present on Windows for win32 API calls. Native Windows compilers typically use some form of fastcall, or cdecl.

Comment: So, linux supports `cdecl` only?

Comment: @David: actually they tend to use `__stdcall` or `__cdecl`, as the entirety of the WINAPI is `__stdcall` or `__cdecl`, I never once encountered a compiler that defaults to `__fastcall` nor and API that makes extensive use of it

Comment: @Necrolis My day to day compiler, Delphi, uses fastcall by default. MSVC defaults to fastcall for C++ member functions.

Comment: @Alcott It's not even that simple. Consider x64. On both Windows and Linux (don't know about Mac), there only is one x64 calling convention.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Delphi isn't C or C++ though, and MSVC uses `__thiscall`, not `__fastcall`, as the default for member functions, except COM interfaces which default to `__stdcall`

Comment: @Necrolis You mentioned `__fastcall`. I never did that. I talked about the generic concept of `fastcall`. C and C++ are not the only languages in existence.

Comment: @David: I suppose, however this question is tagged for C or C++

Comment: @Necrolis I know. I'm just fighting the cause of the little downtrodden guy!

Comment: I'm not sure, but afaik Delphi register is not entirely compatible to MS __fastcall. I would check that properly before attempting that.

Comment: Please, forget you ever heard about calling conventions unless you're writing a compiler or operating system or something. It's a huge mess of complexity and incompatibility dealing with multiple nonstandard calling conventions on a single platform, and for ridiculously small gains.

Answer (score 5):

1. It'll only insert code after the call, which is to reset the stack pointer, so long as there where call arguments.*
2. `__stdcall` generates no cleanup code at the call site, however, it should be noted that compilers can accrue stack cleanup from multiple `__cdecl` calls into one cleanup, or it can delay the cleanup to prevent pipeline stalls.
3. Ignoring the inverted order in this example, no, it'll only insert code to cleanup the `__cdecl` function, setting up of function arguments is something different (different compilers generate/prefer different methods).
4. `__stdcall` was more a windows thing, see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions). the size of the binary depends on the number of calls to the `__cdecl` funcs, more calls means more clean up code, where as `__stdcall` has only 1 singular instance of cleanup code. however, you shouldn't see that much size increase, as at most you have a few bytes per call.

*Its important to distinguish between cleanup and setting up call parameters.

Comment: If no code is inserted to clean up the `__stdcall` function, then how will the stack get cleaned up? Do you mean, the frame stack of the `__stdcall` function will just vanishes when the function finishes, which means the stack gets cleaned up?

Comment: @Alcott: no worries, I have many typo's through my SO answers :(

Comment: @Alcott: I change the wording a little, `__stdcall` functions embed their cleanup code in the function itself (with stack cleanup done by the return, see the `RETN imm8/imm16` assembly instruction), `__cdecl` functions require the compiler to emit the cleanup at ever call site that has arguments (this allows var arg functions).

Comment: Got it. So, setting up call parameters in `__cdecl` and `__stdcall` differs?

Comment: @Alcott: nope, they will be set up the same way

Comment: @Necrolis So `__stdcall` is different from the older `__pascal` (or whatever it was?  (I've not looked at it, but `__cdecl` and `__stdcall` could push the arguments in the opposite order.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: `__cdecl` and `__stdcall` both push from right to left order, but in terms of the difference between `__pascal` and `__stdcall`, `__pascal` pushes from left to right

Comment: Depending on ABI, arguments might also be on the FPU stack, and in SSE2 registers

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort: I would like to know of an ABI other that x64 that allows stdcall/cdecl to use SSE registers or the FP stack to pass args, AFAIK stdcall & cdecl must *always* use the main stack for argument passing

Comment: FPU regs & cdecl : PowerPC :-) But on x86 it is indeed more a fastcall property I guess.

Answer (score 4):

Historically, the first C++ compilers used the equivalent of
`__stdcall`.  From a quality of implementation point of view, I'd expect
the C compiler to use the `__cdecl` convensions, and the C++ compiler
the `__stdcall` (which were known as the Pascal convensions back then).
This is one thing that the early Zortech compiles got right.

Of course, vararg functions must still use `__cdecl` conventions.  The
callee can't clean up the stack if it doesn't know how much to clean up.

(Note that the C standard was carefully designed to allow the 
`__stdcall` conventions in C as well.  I only know of one compiler which
took advantage of this, however; the amount of existing code at the time
which called vararg functions without a prototype in view was enormous,
and while the standard declared it broken, compiler implementors didn't
want to break their clients' code.)

In a lot of milieu, there seems to be a very strong tendency to insist
that the C and the C++ conventions be the same, that one can take the
address of an `extern "C++"` function, and pass it to a function written
in C which calls it.  IIRC, for example, g++ doesn't treat

```
extern "C" void f();
```

and

```
void f();
```

as having two different types (although the standard requires it), and
allows passing the address of a static member function to
`pthread_create`, for example.  The result is that such compilers use
the exact same conventions everywhere, and on Intel, they are the
equivalent of `__cdecl`.

Many compilers have extensions to support other convensions.  (Why they
don't use the standard `extern "xxx"`, I don't know.)  The syntax for
these extensions is very varied, however.  Microsoft puts the attribute
directly before the function name:

```
void __stdcall func( int, int );
```

, g++ puts it in a special attribute clause after the function
declaration:

```
void func( int, int ) __attribute__((stdcall));
```

The C++11 has added a standard way of specifying attributes:

```
void [[stdcall]] func( int, int );
```

It doesn't specify `stdcall` as an attribute, but it *does* specify that
additional attributes (other than those defined in the standard) may be
specified, and are implementation dependent.  I expect that both g++ and
VC++ accept this syntax in their most recent versions, at least if C++11
is activated.  The exact name of the attribute (`__stdcall`, `stdcall`,
etc.) may vary, however, so you probably want to wrap this in a macro.

Finally: in a modern compiler with optimization turned on, the
difference in the calling conventions is probably negligible.
Attributes like `const` (not to be confused with the C++ keyword
`const`), `regparm` or `noreturn` will probably have a larger impact,
both in terms of executable size and performance.

Comment: If I simply define a function like this: `void foo();`, then is it `__cdecl`?

Comment: C++ could not use __cdecl, because __cdecl does not have knowledge of the object pointer <this>. They had to use a different calling convention. AFAIK, Microsoft calls it __thiscall...

Comment: @Malkocoglu: C++ can easily use `__cdecl`, the `this` would just be passed on the stack, just like its done for stdcall based COM interfaces

Comment: @Necrolis: Yes, for class-member vararg functions, they use the scheme you described. Yet, a C program can not call this special kind of __cdecl, because it does not know about <this> object pointer ! From a binary point of view, they are different...

Comment: @Malkocoglu: you'd just define a dummy param to place hold the `this` pointer (again see COM interfaces, especially Direct X). but C couldn't call class member functions with invoking UB or the use of special interfaces like COM anyways...

Comment: @Necrolis: Yes yes, you are right. I just do not know much about COM !

Comment: @Alcott It depends on what your compiler defaults are.  Which in turn depends on the command line options passed to the compiler, at least for VC++ (options `/Gd`, `/Gr` and `/Gz`---I think you get `__cdecl` if you don't specify anything).  The default for g++ is always the equivalent of `__cdecl`.

Answer (score 2):

This calling convention crowd is history by the new **64-bit ABI**.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions

There is also the ABI side of things for different architectures. (like **ARM**)
Not everything executes the same for all architectures. So do not bother thinking about this calling convention thing !

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention

EXE size improvement is insignificant (maybe nonexistent), do not bother...

`__cdecl` is much more flexible than `__stdcall`. Variable number of arguments flexibility, the insignificance of cleanup code (instruction), `__cdecl` function can be called with wrong number of arguments and this does not necessarily cause a serious problem ! But the same situation with `__stdcall` always goes wrong !

Comment: The 64-bit API is only used when compiling in 64 bit mode (if at all---it wouldn't surprise me if there were still additional options).  And if you've written correct C++ (and the compiler will complain if you don't), or even correct C (but the compiler can't know in the case of C, and a lot of legacy code is not "correct" according to the C standard), using `__stdcall` is no problem (since the conventions in `__stdcall` for calling a vararg function are the same as in `__cdecl`).

Comment: @james Kanze: The two 64 bit API's (Microsoft and EveryoneElse) do not have options or variants similar to `__stdcall` or `cdecl`.

Comment: @MSalters Such options or variants aren't generally part of the official API.  A compiler could still offer them.  (For that matter, a compiler could use some sort of global code generation, and use different calling conventions for each function, depending what the function did with the arguments.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: That's of course quite possible when a compiler sees both caller and callee. But in that case, optimization can do truly weird things with calling conventions anyway (often as a side-effect, e.g. when reordering instructions that came from prologs or epilogs). In the "Everyone Else" case, there might be interoperability issues if the caller and callee are compiled with different compilers and non-standard options - a linker in general cannot patch that up.

Comment: @MSalters Yes.  Once the compiler can see both caller and callee, anything goes, and we can't really talk about an ABI.  Extending the compiler to support additional calling conventions is an intermediate solution: you're guaranteeing that the callee and all of the callers will be compiled with a compiler which supports the additional calling conventions.  (I can imagine calling conventions which would be optimal for certain types of functions only.  You write that type of function, add the attribute declaration, and get faster code.)

Comment: @MSalters And you'd be surprised what linkers can do.  You can patch up just about anything with the insertion of a thunk, and I've used linkers which did (converting Fortran calling conventions to Cobol, for example---and as you can imagine, that was some time ago).

Comment: @JamesKanze: It's true that "calling convention" and ABI are slightly vague terms. One specific edge case I just ran across is `__noreturn`. As you can imagine, that does have some effect on epilog code generation.

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered the other parts of your question, so I'll just add my answer about the size:

> 4.Finally, back to the quoted words, why __stdcall results in smaller executable than __cdecl?

That appears to not be true. I tested it by compiling [libudis](https://github.com/vmt/udis86/tree/master/libudis86) with and without the stdcall calling convention. First without:

```
$ clang -target i386-pc-win32 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Os -I.. -I/usr/include -fPIC -c *.c && strip *.o
$ du -cb *.o
6524    decode.o
95932   itab.o
1434    syn-att.o
1706    syn-intel.o
2288    syn.o
1245    udis86.o
109129  totalt
```

And with. It is the `-mrtd` switch that enables stdcall:

```
$ clang -target i386-pc-win32 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Os -I.. -I/usr/include -fPIC -mrtd -c *.c && strip *.o
7084    decode.o
95932   itab.o
1502    syn-att.o
1778    syn-intel.o
2296    syn.o
1305    udis86.o
109897  totalt
```

As you can see, cdecl beats stdcall with a few hundred bytes. It could be my testing methodology that is flawed, or clang's stdcall code generator is weak. But I think that with modern compilers the extra flexibility afforded by caller cleanup means that they will always generate better code with cdecl rather than stdcall.